# Remove street number from addresses

Tags: php

I want to extract out the street number from an address string, e.g., I want "123 Oak St." to be "Oak St."

Currently I have:

```
$street = trim(str_replace(range(0,9),'', $address)); // remove all numbers
```

This works fine in most cases but not when the street name itself contains a number, e.g., 42nd st.

So I'm trying to figure out how to only remove the first string of consecutive characters (i.e., no whitespace in between) that is all numerical characters.

Comment: No, it should stay 42nd st.

Comment: @BenDavidow: `$street = preg_replace('/\s?\d+\s?/', '', $address);` might suit your needs.

Comment: @RahilWazir, He's saying "123 42nd st" should return "42nd st"

Comment: be careful this could easily go wrong "1\8 X road" "unit 4, 9 K st" better to let users specify there own format

Comment: Watch out for addresses like "221b Baker Street"

Comment: @MarkBaker: +1 for the Sherlock reference :D

Comment: I am bit extended @AmalMurali 's suggestion in my case: ```$address = str_ireplace(['flat', 'floor'], '', preg_replace('/\s?\d+\s?/', '', $address));```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `preg_replace`

```
<?php
$v = '123 Oak St.';
$pattern = '/\S*\s(.*)/';
echo preg_replace($pattern , "$1", $v);
```

https://ideone.com/lxm581